# Using a single Cosmos DB Account per tenant

Tags: asp.net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have a multi-tenant SaaS application, B2B context.
Tenants range from small (100s MB) to very high data size (100s GB).
Our current setup in Cosmos DB is:
Database per domain
Container per tenant

So:
Database orders

- Tenant X container
- Tenant Y container
- Tenant Z container
  Database payments
- Tenant X container
- Tenant Y container
- Tenant X container

We use DB-level provisioned throughput, with autopilot enabled.

We were investigating going to the serverless version, as we are using this already for another application and works very good. There are some constraints we need to take into account (size, max throughput, etc), but the biggest constraint is gone: Additional containers are free!

This means we are now investigating going for one of two models:

- One DB Account, database per tenant (with X containers)
  PRO: Manageability, coding easiness (what we have currently works)
  CONS: Not all services in Azure support this data seggregation natively (think of Synapse), so having some services enabled for some specific tenants make it difficult. Backups are not easy as inplace backup is not supported
- Multiple DB accounts, one db account per tenant (with x databases/containers)
  PRO: Complete data seggregation, in line with our storage accounts (one per tenant). Azure services make it easy supporting this architecture. Backup is easy as it's just a matter of linking the tenant to the new account.
  CONS: Manageability, we will have plenty of DB accounts. Code complexity. We use Cosmos DB .NET SDK, one singleton CosmosClient, which will require quite some plumbing to support this model. We will also need to change tenant provisioning to also set up a new cosmos db account

Did anyone go for one of both options, and why? Any additional pro/cons you can share and are there any limits (besides soft limits) we need to be aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question borders on opinion but there are some objective things to understand when designing multi-tenant applications on Cosmos DB.

First the minimum cost per tenant depends on where throughput is provisioned. Using DB-level throughput the minimum cost per container is ~$1/month. However the problem with DB-level throughput is you cannot get predictable performance for containers (tenants) within that database. This is especially true is you have asymmetric tenant sizes

Second, the design you use should be based upon whether you have symmetric or asymmetric tenants. Yours appear to be asymmetric. For this reason you need a varied approach. Tenant per container is not going to work with DB-level throughput because you will have noisy neighbor problem between tenants. You will need to isolate larger tenants in their own container.

Third consideration is cost. Cost per tenant for DB-level throughput is <$1/tenant (~400 RU/s = $25/month / 25 containers in database with DB-level throughput). Cost per tenant with container-level throughput is $25. There is a third option which is tenant per logical partition. Marginal cost per tenant here is zero. However the max size is 20GB and also potential for same noisy neighbor problem

Given all this my recommendation for most is to use tenant per logical partition for small tenants and tenant per container for larger ones. For smaller tenants you need to put some sort of resource governance in place to prevent noisy neighbor problems, however this is something required of any multi-tenant application. When tenants get too large or want to upgrade, then migrate them into their own container, with their own throughput.

There is a talk on this subject that is worth checking out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOQoQnQqwwU) that goes into more details.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your reply! I've seen the presentation indeed, but I miss some more intel around the account per tenant approach. Especially with the serverless option, the 'minimum' cost is really dismissable, as such I'd like to go for a one-size-fits-all approach by using an account per tenant in serverless, with unlimited containers (but with size/ru restriction). I'm trying to understand would there be any implications for this. 
Again, we won't have 1000s of tenants as this is a niche B2B application. The min. cost of 24dollar is OK btw (our current design is like this)

Comment: Account per tenant has the same $24/month cost so no different than tenant/container. You also get flexibility with where you replicate too. Serverless will eventually get higher limits. I can't what those will be. It also will eventually get the ability to migrate from serverless to provisioned throughput so you could start with serverless, then upgrade to provisioned in the future.

Comment: I'm in contact with Thomas he gave me the to be limits (20kRU per container and 1TB). So you see no issues with going for that approach?

Comment: Yes, for sure that can certainly work. I see no issues using it.